# A more elegant way of escaping dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

OK, so I've got this line of code in a search stored procedure:

```
SET @where = 'job_code = ''' + REPLACE(@job_code, '''', '''''') + ''''
```

and there are basically two operations I'd like to streamline -**the first being surrounding the concatenated value in single quotes.** Obviously, in the above statement, I'm escaping a `'` by using two `''` and then ending the string with a `'` so I can concatenate the actual value. There's got to be a better way!

**The second of the operations** would be the `REPLACE(@job_code, '''', '''''')` where I'm escaping any single quotes that might exist in the field.

**Isn't there a much more elegant way of writing this line of code as a whole?**

I thought it was the `ESCAPE` keyword but that's tied tightly to the `LIKE` statement, so no go there.

Comment: Have you considered passing directly as a variable to your dynamic SQL instead of concatenating it? I know going with the hardcoded value is better for avoiding parameter sniffing issues, but depending on the workload this might be a simpler option.

Comment: @Love2Learn, it's not something I've considered -but after thinking about it I'm pretty sure I want to shy away from it because I want to keep the stored procedure pristine so that it can be used by any consumer. Adding that type of assumption would make it more difficult to keep it consumable.

Comment: Using a variable for `'` will make it slightly more readable, but its not a massive improvement.

Comment: Can you explain "used by any consumer"? I would argue that passing it as a parameter to your dynamic SQL could be considered more consumable since as long as you can get it into a datatype that can be passed to a dynamicSQL statment you can use it without worrying about escaping anything.

Comment: @Love2Learn, so what I'm saying is that if I'm forcing the consumer to escape the data -that's at best quite different from how you might consider consuming this procedure. Or any other procedure for that matter. You see a procedure, pass it the values, and expect it to manipulate the data.

Comment: Looks like I wasn't explaining myself correctly. The `sp_executeSQL` solution is the one I was trying to suggest. ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not sure how you execute your sql query, if you use sp_executesql, could be something like this

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          N'SELECT * FROM YouTable WHERE job_code = @job_code',
          N'@job_code varchar(100)',
          @job_code = @job_code;
```

Comment: Now this is an interesting option -because it handles a couple interesting scenarios. I can write my SQL to handle `null` values much easier this way, there are less branches when it comes to `if` statements, and at the same time I don't have to escape anything. Interesting my friend!

Comment: +1: This is the solution I was picturing and the nice thing about it is you can populate @job_code anyway you want without worrying about any escaping.

Comment: Added bonuses are you get plan reuse and less plan cache bloat.

Answer (score 6):

The parameterized query answer is probably the real "right answer", but to answer your original question, what you want is [QUOTENAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).  More specifically, the single-quote version:

```
SET @where = 'job_code = ' + QUOTENAME(@job_code, '''')
```

Do note the length limit on this (input is a `sysname`, meaning 128 characters), though, as it is intended to quote the names of database objects and not as a general-purpose mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare constants:

```
declare @SQ as char(1) = ''''

SET @where = 'job_code = ' + @SQ + REPLACE(@job_code, @SQ, @SQ + @SQ) + @SQ
```

Comment: +1 for a solution I had not yet considered. I'm not sure I want to do it that way, as I'm not sure it's any better (**personally speaking**) than the one I'm using now -but a +1 nonetheless!

Comment: Yep, I don't know if I'd do it either - still not all that easy to read, but it's an option.

Comment: Sorry if I seem harsh, but this is lipstick on a pig. ErikZ's answer is the cleanest solution and is the way that MS intend dynamic SQL to be generated, even back in SQL Server 2000. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172445%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: @DeanOC Yep, that's why EricZ's answer got 23 upvotes including one from me - it's clearly the best answer for many dynamic SQL scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function that handles your typical scenarios, something like:

```
create function WrapAndReplaceQuotes (@input as varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    return '''' + replace(@input, '''', '''''') + ''''
end

SET @where = 'job_code = ' + WrapAndReplaceQuotes(@job_code)
```

Comment: This would certainly make the `SET` statement a lot more elegant, let me consider this one for a bit.